# Why different output between sum and my code

Tags: python

I made a list and When I sum the list items with for loop, I get wrong output.

I tried the i def to equal 0.

```
list2=[4,6,8]
i=0
for i in list2:
    i = i+i
print(i)
// output 16

sum(list2)
// output 18
```

Comment: On the last loop through of your for loop, you have i = 8+8 which is 16.

Comment: `for i ... i = i + i` makes no sense.

Comment: yes I figured out.

Answer (score 0):

On the last loop through of your for loop, you have i = 8+8 which is 16.

Try this instead:

```
list2 = [4,6,8]
acc=0
for i in list2:
  acc += i
print(acc)
```

Comment: Yes I change it to. It worked thanks for your answer.